# How to import module(alias) whoes namespace's prefix equals own namespace's suffix in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

When I compile code below, tsc compiler output error message.

Code:

```
module a {
    export class Foo {}
}
module b.a {
    import Foo = a.Foo;
    class Bar {}
}
```

Error message:

```
sample.ts(5,5): error TS2305: Module 'b.a' has no exported member 'Foo'.
```

Could you tell me why compile error occer ?
And If any solution ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` in the context of a module `a` (including the submodule `b.a`) refers to the module `a`. This is just necessary given how the code for modules is generated.

You can create an alias somewhere where the 'wrong' `a` is not visible:

```
module a {
    export class Foo {}
}

import global_a = a;
module b.a {
    import Foo = global_a.Foo;
    class Bar {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understood. And I will use "_" instead "."(b.a -> b_a). If my solution is problematic, I would appreciate if you tell me.